# How to Select a Textbox on Click to Input Keypads Output

Tags: java, swing, textbox, actionlistener, keypad

Interface

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAvOJ.png]

Above image shows the interface i am trying to implement. log in panel and keypad panel need to somehow work together, so whenever i click on the selected text box i can use the keypad to enter the required input.

On correct detail entry the log in panel will change to another panel with other text boxes so the keypad will have to work with these too.

Any ideas ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: so you want to know how to implement a keyboard to your application

Comment: (1-) What is a textbox? There is no Swing class with that name. It looks to me like you are using a JTextField. So be specific, when asking a question!

Comment: Yeah sorry, First time using this ;/ and i am still a beginner to java. Yes JTextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `TextAction` to create an `Action` to be shared by each button. The `TextAction` allows you to access the last focused text component:

```
Action numberAction = new TextAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent input = getFocusedComponent();
        input.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
    }
};

JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
button1.addActionListener( numberAction );
JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
button2.addActionListener( numberAction );
...
```

You would need to create a separate Action for the "Clear" button.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve IMO would be to `setFocusable(false)` on all of your JButtons, so only the two input fields can be focus owners. You also should have a FocusListener for those two TextFields so you know if the user clicks a button where that number should go

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You could have a JTextField to keep track of the currently selected textbox and then add FocusListeners to your JTextFields to update the currently selected textbox when foxus is gained or lost.

Something like this:

```
JTextField currentText;
final JTextField textField = new JTextField("Ayy");
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        //Your code here
        currentText = textField;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        //Your code here
        currentText = null;
    }
});
```